# Motion of a charged particle in 3 dimensions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, projectile-motion

Our problem was this: describe the motion of the particle in each of the 3 dimensions. The particle starts at the origin at rest. $\overrightarrow E$ and $ \overrightarrow B$ are both constant and point in the $x$ direction.

What I don't understand is where the complexity is. The particle, when released from rest, will begin to move in the $x$ direction. It will accelerate up to a constant velocity and then stay at that velocity.

However, my classmates were deriving answers that showed that the motion of the particle in the $y$ and $z$ directions were something involving sine and cosine.

To clarify: what *type* of initial motion in the $yz$ direction must the particle have in order to create circular motion around the $x$-axis? Linear, quadratic, etc...?

Comment: The initial state isn't what is critical; rather, it is the potential the particle is in that determines the eq. of motion. ... Oh, is this quantum mechanics? A free particle in QM is a travelling wave-packet, which is constructed by sines and cosines.

Comment: @Lovsovs that argument seems too flimzy, if I may say so. I mean, does it have to be a quantum mechanical particle?

Comment: It is also totally unclear if you are asking about a charged particle in the presence of electric and magnetic fields or are asking about the propagation of an electromagnetic wave or neither, for that matter.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat No, I was trying to understand what you were saying: You were referring to an incident in which your classmates got some answer involving trigonometric functions, and I asked if that incident involved QM, since that is one example of a free particle being described by trig-functions. EDIT: I just now realized that you meant the electric and magnetic fields, which makes the question more sensible - you should probably edit your question to make this more clear.

Comment: @Lovsovs I think it was a QM particle, but can it work for a classical particle?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat If this was in a standard introductory EM-course, the particle should be treated as being classical.

Answer (score 1):

For a charged particle in a uniform magnetic field to experience uniform circular motion, it is necessary that the magnetic field $B$ be oriented orthogonally to the particle's velocity. If what you say is true that the electric field $E$ and the magnetic field $B$ are pointing in the same direction, then there will be no uniform circular motion since, as you note, the particle will accelerate in the $x$-direction. By the Lorentz force law, the force on the particle is
$$
F = qE + qv\times B = qE,
$$
since $v\times B = 0$ because $v$ and $B$ are parallel. Now, if $B$ pointed in the $y$-direction, say, you may see uniform circular motion.

Let's say that the particle starts with some velocity in the $y,z$-plane. That is, $v_0 = (0, v_y, v_z)$ and $r_0 = (0, -R, 0)$. Then, the force exerted by the magnetic field on the charged particle is $F = ma = qv\times B = qvB$. Since the velocity in the $y,z$ plane is orthogonal to the magnetic field which points in the $x$-direction, the force is centripetal. And thus, we have that $a = \omega^2 R$, where $R$ is the initial radius the charge starts at with respect to the origin.

Hence, $m\omega^2R = qvB \implies \omega = \sqrt{qvB/mR}$, and it should be apparent that the magnetic field can only produce a centripetal acceleration. Hence,
$$
ma = qE + qv\times B \\
m\ddot x = qE_x \\
m\omega^2R = qv_{y,z}B
$$
together imply that $r(t) = \tfrac{q}{m}(\tfrac{1}{2}E_xt^2, -R\cos{\omega t}, R\sin{\omega t}).$ Working out the details is a matter of integrating a few times and understanding the parametrization of circular motion.

Comment: That's what I understood, yet the professor went on thinking that his answer was correct. He later mumbled something about him forgetting to mention that the $x$ component of the particle's initial motion can be zero but for his intended final motion to be apparent, he needed to say something about the particle's initial motion in the $y$ and $z$ direction. That's the part I missed. So what initial conditions of the particle's motion lead to this final motion?

Comment: Basically what I'm asking is that could circular motion be achieved with an initial $v_y$ and $v_z$?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat yes, in fact the only way for circular motion to be achieved is if there is a component in the y or z directions.

Comment: If the particle starts at rest, it will indeed move only in the $x$ direction.  However, if it starts with some velocity in the $yz$ plane, you get a circular motion in the $yz$ plane plus your motion in the $x$ direction.  I suspect that is what the professor was mumbling.

Comment: Ok, now my main question: what type of motion must the$yz$ components have? Linear, quadratic, constant? I intuitively arrived at the fact that it must have some type of motion in these directions, but I can't figure out what kind.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat the components have to be constant. I will update my answer with more details momentarily.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat just finished updating my answer. Let me know if you're still confused.